# Securely connecting two applications with mTLS using Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, tcp, reverse-proxy, mtls

I have two applications running on different hosts that communicate over TCP. I want to implement encrypted TCP connections with client authentication (mTLS) between them, but I don't want to implement this logic on the application level. Instead, I'm considering using Nginx as a reverse proxy (TCP upstream) to handle the mTLS connections. However, I'm new to SSL and don't know where to start. Can someone guide me on how to create the necessary certificates for this example, set up Nginx to handle mTLS, and confirm if this approach is feasible? I have created a diagram to illustrate my setup and have found some helpful links, which I've included below.

[image: diagram]

[link from smallstep.com](https://smallstep.com/hello-mtls/doc/server/nginx)

[securing-http-traffic-upstream](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/)

[ngx_stream_ssl_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html)

[ngx_stream_proxy_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well. I ended up with this [example](https://github.com/JadKHaddad/Nginx-mTLS)